# How to submit Google form and bypass login with "Limit to 1 response"?

Tags: node.js, cookies, google-forms

I'm trying to submit a form on Google without running into the following response:

[image: Sign in to continue]

How it's usually done is I use a URL and make a GET request to submit.

Take, for example, the following form: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdls8ZHN0eT2UIKdC2FM730McPOxVPbY3WVJzsxtMQr5vKD1A/viewform

All I have to do to submit it is to change the endpoint to `formResponse`, incorporate the fields into the URL, add the `submit=Submit` into it, and it works like a charm:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdls8ZHN0eT2UIKdC2FM730McPOxVPbY3WVJzsxtMQr5vKD1A/formResponse?entry.672765353=name&entry.869555934=a%40b.co&entry.401439447=Google&entry.401439447.other_option_response=&entry.600725028=5&entry.1681264=thanks&fvv=1&fbzx=7560642045451257680&pageHistory=0&_=1566978567993

Of course, just to be sure, I add `history=0`, `fvv=1`, and `usp=pp_url`. It works fine, and you may test it.

Unfortunately, when I add the setting to "Limit to 1 response", things get a bit more complicated:
[image: Form Settings]

This is the form with the "Limit to 1 response" enabled: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSckF711cZNHGhRKtH5GfV8_onCtuwYsHDgFD0E64MdCxWy1Ew/viewform

When I try to submit, it tells me to log in, which I want to avoid:

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSccTvwF-YYvto4LukP_GW4uXifU0qO22p6RI-uAWOLboVSdfA/formResponse?entry.883406982=Option+1&emailAddress=test@example.co&submit=Submit

Is there any way to bypass this? I am trying to let users submit through my own portal and process it through a GET request in the backend Node server.